# Laravel to echo other fields except primary in HasOne method

Tags: model, laravel, eloquent, has-one

In Laravel i'm trying to make output, relational data with Model using `hasOne`.

**My tables are:**

```
User
--------
id name  country_id    
1  Hakan   1

Country
--------
id country
1   Turkey
```

**My Model is given below:**

```
class User extends Eloquent{

public function country() {
        return $this->hasOne('Country','id','country');
    }

}
```

**view code:**

```
$country = User::find(1)->country;
```

When I run this code, it outputs `id` of country but I want to echo Country Name. I tried and searched but couldn't find any help.

Comment: You need to share more code. This view code you shared does nothing, just assigns a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your table relation below

```
User
--------
id name  country_id    
1  Hakan   1

Country
--------
id country
1   Turkey
```

Your relation in the model should be

```
class User extends Eloquent{
    public function country() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Country');
    }
}
```

So you can get country name using

```
$country = User::find(1)->country;
echo $country->country;
```

If you want to use something like this

```
$users = Country::find(1)->users;
echo $users->first()->name; // get the first user's name
echo $users->get(1)->name; // get the second user's name
```

Then you may use `hasMany` in your `Country` model like

```
class Country extends Eloquent {
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your edit and reply... i asked my problem wrong but with your update it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

When you run `$country = User::find(1)->country;`, `$country` will now hold an instance of your `Country` model. If you want to access the country name, you'll need to get it via a property of said model:

```
echo $country->country;
```